# Альтернатива плагину gulp-delete-unused-images

Tags: gulp

Некорректно работает модуль `gulp-delete-unused-images`, есть ли ему какая-то альтернатива? Нашел модуль `gulp-unused-images`, но он не удаляет неиспользуемые изображения.